# вопрос про mysql запрос

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, есть таблица questions с полем answers (int), и есть таблица answers с полем (question_id)

как можно обновить поле answers у всех questions, чтобы было  ровно столько записей сколько есть записей в таблице  answers с полем questions_id = id запись в questions

Comment: А зачем вам поле answers ? существование этого поля является избыточным и его надо постоянно обновлять. в таких случаях принято не создавать поле, а вычислять количество на ходу. если все таки хотите его сделать, то сначала сделайте сделайте запрос который получит количества в разрезе q_id (используйте group by и count()) а потом воспользоваться формой update с join где в качестве присоединяемой таблицы использовать получившийся на первом этапе запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, можно так:

```
UPDATE `questions` q 
SET q.`answers` = (
        SELECT COUNT(`question_id`) 
        FROM `answers` a 
        WHERE a.`question_id` = q.`id`
)
```

Но как правильно подметил **@Mike** в комментарии:

> Существование этого поля является избыточным и его надо постоянно обновлять. в таких случаях принято не создавать поле, а вычислять количество на ходу.

Comment: зато меньше нагрузки, при выводе количества, просто выбрать значение из столбца, и не делать пробег по всей базе выбирая кол-во записей

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
  questions q left join 
      (select count(aa.id) as c, aa.questions_id 
        from answers aa 
        group by aa.questions_id) a 
  on a.questions_id=q.id
  set q.answers=a.c;
```

Тест: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4c853/1